# jQuery Syntax on formatting date

Tags: jquery, syntax

I'm using the jQuery datepicker to append the date as a parameter on the end of the url. It all works fine but I want to format the date as follows:

$('#datepicker').datepicker({inline: true, dateFormat: 'ddmmyy'});

When I try this on line 7 of the code below the 'onSelect' does not work and simply populates the input field, I'm obviously getting the syntax or brackets or something wrong?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></scrip>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {       
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ <!-- The issue is here -->
onSelect : function (dateText, inst) {   
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var datepickedup = $("input#datepicker").val();
window.location.href = (pathname + "?startdate=" + datepickedup);
('#myform').submit();
}
});   
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id='myform' method="post">
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add all options inside of a pair of brackets.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            inline: true,
            dateFormat: 'ddmmyy',
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                var pathname = window.location.pathname;
                var datepickedup = $("input#datepicker").val();
                window.location.href = (pathname + "?startdate=" + datepickedup);
                ('#myform').submit();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Explaining what you changed might help

Comment: `you should add all options inside of a pair of brackets.` it was already inside a pair of brackets.

Comment: @KevinB  he changed "$('#datepicker').datepicker({ " on the line 7 to "$('#datepicker').datepicker({inline: true, dateFormat: 'ddmmyy'});" so, onSelect was not included in options any more.

Comment: @ErcanPeker wha? in both cases onSelect is included in the options... where it belongs... the only difference i see from the original is the removal of the html comment.

Comment: after changing his code line 7, it probably looked like this: https://codepen.io/peker-ercan/pen/mzRVpe . as you see, onSelect won't be in options brackets.